# Post JSON OBJECT IN JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have Json text:

```
{"searchParams":{"cnt":5,"Bounds":{"NorthEast": "Latitude":"48.5166043488675","Longitude":"-67.5"},"SouthWest":{"Latitude":"25.7207351344121","Longitude":"-126.38671875"}},"HomesAvailableNow":[0],"BrandId":[4]}}
```

I have url = http://www.mypage.com/AjaxWebServices/MapService.asmx/FilterByQueryString and I want to post request and receive data.

please help me...

Answer (score 2):

Use URLConnection to post data:

```
String data = "json";

URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection conn;
conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush(); 
// Get the response 
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); 
String line; 
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
    // Process line... 
    } 
wr.close(); 
rd.close(); 
return rd.toString();
```